# how to place tooltip over a point in canvas Easeljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, easeljs

Hey I have build a canvas([EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs)) which its components are:

1.2 circles

2.One coordinate system around it

3.several black points around it.

now for each black point, I want to have a tooltip which is open when ever the user is clicked on it.

I have succeeded in building the tooltip, but the placement of the tooltip is not on the right spot.

The tip element is an **DOMElement** Class of easeljs library, I am showing the tip on each click of each point.

I have problems when I am trying to position the tooltip. 
I am trying to get the coordinates(x,y) of current event and using these coordinates I am position the tooltip. But so far, the position of the tooltip isn't stable and and tip is shown not above the point but beside it or beneath the point.

The code can be found also in codepen:
http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/AXZxKN

I am adding the source code, you must look in the following lines:

```
var g = new createjs.Graphics().f("black").dc(0,0,5);
for (var i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
    var p = new createjs.Shape(g);
  var d = data[i];
  p.x = d[0] * GRAPH_WIDTH;
  p.y = GRAPH_HEIGHT - d[1] * GRAPH_HEIGHT;
  p.on("click", handleMouseClickEvent(d[0],d[1]));
  stage.addChild(p);
}
  stage.update(); 

   function handleMouseClickEvent(arg1,arg2) {
      return function reallyHandleMouseClickEvent(event) {
        console.log("you clicked the black point", event, arg1,arg2);
        tip.visible = true;
        tip.x = event.target.x ;
        tip.y = event.target.y ;
        stage.update();
       }
     }
```

```js
$(function(){
var stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas2d');
var circle1 = new createjs.Shape();
var circle2 = new createjs.Shape();
var rect = new createjs.Shape();
 var data = [
  [0.8, 0.8],
  [0.9, 0.4],
  [0.75, 0.25],
  [0.95, 0.1]
];
 
rect.graphics.beginFill("#32CD32");
rect.graphics.drawRect(50, 0, 500, 455);
rect.graphics.endFill();
stage.addChild(rect);
var lablelOne = new createjs.DOMElement("lablelOne")
lablelOne.x = 10;
lablelOne.y = 170;
lablelOne.rotation = 90;
stage.addChild(lablelOne);
stage.update(); 
var lablelTwo = new createjs.DOMElement("lablelTwo")
lablelTwo.x = 170;
lablelTwo.y = 500;
stage.addChild(lablelTwo);
stage.update();
var tip = new createjs.DOMElement("tip");
tip.visible = false;
stage.addChild(tip);
stage.update();
circle2.graphics.beginFill("yellow").drawCircle(0, 0, 300);
circle2.x = 500;
circle2.y = 0;
stage.addChild(circle2);
circle1.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 150);
circle1.x = 500;
circle1.y = 0;
stage.addChild(circle1);
//stage.addChild(rect);
stage.update();
var coord_xaxis = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_xaxis);
var coord_yaxis = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_yaxis);
var coord_arrow_x = new createjs.Shape();
//stage.addChild(coord_arrow_x);
var coord_arrow_y = new createjs.Shape();
//stage.addChild(coord_arrow_y);
var coord_xaxis_lines = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_xaxis_lines);
var coord_yaxis_lines = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_yaxis_lines);
/**$('#canvas2d').width()/15**/
var axis_center_x = $('#canvas2d').width()/10; //here was 14
var axis_center_y = $('#canvas2d').height()/1.10;
var xaxis_width = $('#canvas2d').width()-0.05*$('#canvas2d').width();
var yaxis_width = $('#canvas2d').height()-0.05*$('#canvas2d').height();
var axis_start_x = ($('#canvas2d').width()-xaxis_width)/1.20;
var axis_start_y = ($('#canvas2d').height()-yaxis_width)/6;

var axis_strokewidth = 2;
coord_xaxis.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_xaxis.graphics.moveTo(axis_start_x, axis_center_y).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width, axis_center_y);
coord_yaxis.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_yaxis.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y).lineTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y+yaxis_width);

// draw coordsys arrow for x-axis
var arrwidth = 5;
var arrxtnd = 5;
coord_arrow_x.graphics.beginFill('#000');
coord_arrow_x.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_arrow_x.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y-arrwidth/2).lineTo(axis_center_x+arrwidth, axis_start_y+arrwidth+arrxtnd).lineTo(axis_center_x-arrwidth, axis_start_y+arrwidth+arrxtnd).lineTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y-arrwidth/2);
coord_arrow_x.graphics.endFill();

// draw coordsys arrow for y-axis
coord_arrow_y.graphics.beginFill('#000');
coord_arrow_y.graphics.beginStroke('#000');
coord_arrow_y.graphics.moveTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width+arrwidth/2, axis_center_y).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width-arrwidth-arrxtnd, axis_center_y+arrwidth).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width-arrwidth-arrxtnd, axis_center_y-arrwidth).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width+arrwidth/2, axis_center_y);
coord_arrow_y.graphics.endFill();

var stepdist = xaxis_width/5.25;
var steplinew = 6;
// 10 horizontal lines
var xlines = 10;
var labels_x = [];
for(var i=xlines;i>=0;i--) {
 // little black marker
  coord_yaxis_lines.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1,'round').beginStroke('#000');
        coord_yaxis_lines.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x-steplinew, axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist).lineTo(axis_center_x+steplinew, axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist);
        // labels
        labels_x[i] = new createjs.Text('x', '14px Arial', '#333');
        labels_x[i].x = axis_center_x-12;
        labels_x[i].y = axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist-6; // move up a bit
        stage.addChild(labels_x[i]);
        labels_x[i].text = (i/10);
        labels_x[i].textAlign = 'right';
}
// 12 orthogonal lines
 var stepdist2 = xaxis_width/6.625; 
  var steplinew2 = 6;
var ylines = 10;
var labels_y = [];
for(var i=ylines;i>=1;i--) {
    // dont overdraw y-axis-line
        
        // little black marker
        coord_xaxis_lines.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1,'round').beginStroke('#000');
        coord_xaxis_lines.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2, axis_center_y-steplinew2).lineTo(axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2, axis_center_y+steplinew2);           
        // labels
        labels_y[i] = new createjs.Text('x', '14px Arial', '#333');
        labels_y[i].x = axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2; // move up a bit
        labels_y[i].y = axis_center_y+12;
        stage.addChild(labels_y[i]);
        labels_y[i].text = (i/10);
        labels_y[i].textAlign = 'center';
}
var GRAPH_WIDTH = 500;
var GRAPH_HEIGHT = 500;
var g = new createjs.Graphics().f("black").dc(0,0,5);
for (var i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
 var p = new createjs.Shape(g);
  var d = data[i];
  p.x = d[0] * GRAPH_WIDTH;
  p.y = GRAPH_HEIGHT - d[1] * GRAPH_HEIGHT;
  p.on("click", handleMouseClickEvent(d[0],d[1]));
  stage.addChild(p);
}
  stage.update(); 
  
   function handleMouseClickEvent(arg1,arg2) {
      return function reallyHandleMouseClickEvent(event) {
        console.log("you clicked the black point", event, arg1,arg2);
        tip.visible = true;
        tip.x = event.target.x ;
        tip.y = event.target.y ;
        stage.update();
       }
     }
  })
```

```css
#canvas2d{
  background-color: white;
}
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fleetRankGraph"> 
<span id="lablelOne" >Critical Index</span>
 <span id="lablelTwo" >Long-term Severity Index</span>
<div id="tip" class="tooltip tooltip-main top in" role="presentation"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">Hello World</div></div>
<canvas id="canvas2d" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, I would recommend transforming the element using CSS, but DOMElement uses CSS transform to position, scale, and rotate DOMElement content, so it will override anything set in CSS.

Instead, you can calculate the additional offset using JQuery. Just access the tip's `htmlElement` (reference to the underlying DIV), and measure its width/height, then subtract what you need from the coordinate.

```
var $tip = $(tip.htmlElement);
tip.x = event.target.x - $tip.width()/2;
tip.y = event.target.y - $tip.height() - 10;
```

If you want to get fancy, you could also ensure it stays in bounds, and then counter-offset the arrow element's position.

Here is an updated pen: http://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/qaWAzk?editors=0010

Cheers.